# Network setup issue

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, switch

I have two internet connection - one broadband connection of 8 Mbps and a lease line of 4 Mbps and CISCO 24 port switch, new dlink 600L router.

Currently both this sources are plugged in Sonic fire wall configured to spill over setting and then distributed via switch.

I want to run approx 30 wireless device including laptops and mobiles and 5 desktop machine.

Please suggest is this infrastructure appropriate or how can i efficiently use my internet bandwidth, as i am facing internet issue (speed issue and device getting disconnected) constantly and unable to figure out the reason behind this.

Plugging directly to the internet source provide great speed tough.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What Internet issue are you experiencing, exactly? We don't offer product recommendations and your question "Please suggest is this infrastructure appropriate" is going to result in a number of opinion based answers so please bear this in mind - you might benefit from updating your question to precisely what your question is... :)

Comment: @Big Chris, I know there would be n number of opinion based on product recommendation. But disclosing my infrastructure would help me to get more precise solution to my problem, letting me know the flaws in my network. :)

Comment: Thanks, but just bear in mind others may also pick up on this. Additionally, you haven't answered my question as to exactly what problem you get when you say "i am facing internet issue constantly and unable to figure out the reason behind this" in your question... this might be the key to finding the real answer for your existing setup.

Comment: @BigChris I am a mobile application developer and has no idea about network infrastructure in detail. Basically my requirement is to run 30 wireless device and 5 desktop max. I need a infrastructure suggestion so to get minimum packet drop/ lose connection/ speed issues due to my network setup and make maximum out of my available bandwidth.  I have also mentioned my existing network details. Here internet issue means the speed issue and device gets auto disconnected some times. Does this explain my issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the 600L, this is a consumer grade device, this is not necessarily bad, but in this case it is. It's a bargain basement product, designed for use in small homes, so 3-4 units max. Running 30+ units over that thing is pure suicide network wise, it has a maximum shared bandwidth of 150mbps for ALL your wireless devices, but the calculator CPU it has on the inside will give up way before that.

Then we get to the sonic wall, all though this isn't a terrible product, they aren't known to be amazing products either, they are mainly VERY small business products and out of the 5 or 6 of these I have had to fix over the years, only 1 of them wasn't underperforming. BUT it is also very important which model it is, because if this unit is also a branch office unit, you might be looking at a maximum of 10 users on this one as well.

As goes for the Cisco 24 port switch, these things are usually pretty damn reliable and shouldn't boast a problem, BUT it depends on the age and model, the age due to how fast it might be or what processor it boasts and the model due to which functionality it has and ability to administrate networks.

As for your network problems, there is a myriad of problems with this setup that can be the cause of the slow network:

- You could have a constricted [VLAN setup](https://documentation.meraki.com/MS/Layer_3_Switching/Layer_3_versus_Layer_2_Switch_for_VLANs)
- Your cabeling could be set up poorly
- You most likely have [routing protocol](https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/thread/63810) mismatches
- Depending on which unit runs your DHCP/DNS these can also be an issue
- Your [spanning tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_Tree_Protocol) could be completely confused and spamming the network

What you really need to do is sit down and get an overview of your network, check what make, model and capability your units have. Then you need to identify the problems with your network, either via the configuration files on your units or by using a network scanner on different parts of your network.

If you want my advice, getting a semi cheap Juniper SRX 100 series to replace your sonic wall, keeping your Cisco for connectivity (but set it up properly) and then either adding in a WLAN controller with WLAN controller enabled Access Points or getting a few Dlink AC3200 or Netgear AC1900 set up in Access point mode with different SSID's might go quite a way to solving your problem. If you also want to fix or change your DHCP/DNS you can get an Asus J1900I-C or an old PC to act as a micro server running linux with [dnsmasq](https://www.iceflatline.com/2010/02/how-to-install-and-configure-dnsmasq/).

Please note that this is a cheap solution and it is not something I would normally recommend to a client, but it will work quite okay if you are on a limited budget.

Tl:dr - Throw everything out and get some proper equipment

Comment: No problem, I added some links to the list over possible problems, to help clarify some of the issues. :)

Comment: Is it possible for you to make some recommendation for device that i can use, I need 1 modem + wifi-router and 1 - wifi router. Because i am really confused which one to buy as i have a budget constraint of $100 per device.

Comment: Well how is your WAN connections connected to the firewall? Because it really depends if you need a firewall/router with a built in modem or if the actual modem part is supplied through RJ45 copper or fiber?
Also at 100$ per unit, you won't get anything worth bothering with anyway, then you are better off with the stuff you have now. So I'd suggest you get a bit bigger budget. Some of the units I suggested in the answer are some of the cheapest you can get if you want it to work reliably and they are 300$ for the router/firewall and about 300$ for the wireless AP.

Comment: I have two internet connection - 
One modem plus router that is connected to WAN giving me 8 Mbps and a cat5e is connected from its port 1 switch to the sonic wall firewall WAN port x01, 
And the other connection is a lease line connection of 4 Mbps and that is connected from its Modem (ASMI-54L) to sonic wall firewall WAN x04 port. 
The sonic firewall-TZ 100 firewall LAN is than connected to cisco 24 port switch.

Comment: Well the best I can really suggest to you then is to get an expanded budget and then get a Juniper srx 100 or 110, they are somewhat easy to install, support load balancing and I have tested one of these to run flawlessly with 25 people. As for the wireless, I would strongly suggest buying a netgear AC1900 and putting it into AP mode, that way it won't disturb the rest of the network.
I'm guessing your cisco unit is also 5-6 years old like the sonic wall and I would strongly suggest replacing it as well.
Also a good read to keep traffic down: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_domain

Comment: Thanks Kris for all your help and efforts you had put in to explain me and helping me out with this issue, it really helped me. :)